# WifiClientSecure Arduino Failed to connect to server

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have an esp-32 cam Ai thinker board. I have connected it to my laptop using FTDI.
Now when i upload this code:

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
// Define your WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "mywifiId";
const char* password = "MyPass";
WiFiClientSecure client;
const char* host = "myproject.cognitiveservices.azure.com";
const int Port = 443;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Connect to WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");



  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s:%d... ", host, Port);
  if (!client.connect(host, Port))
  {
    Serial.println("Failure in connection with the server");

  }

}

void loop() {
}
```

This code connects to wifi successfully but then failed to connect to server.
My server host is correct i doubled check. I have used socket library of Python for testing connection to host. Connection is established successfully using socket libary in Python from my laptop but in arduino ide wificlientsecure give me failed to connect to server.
What could be the problem , please help me with this. Basically I am connecting to my azure host.

Comment: try client.lastError

Answer (score 0):

```
client.setInsecure(); //Add this to connect!
Serial.printf(“Connecting to %s:%d… “, host, Port);
```

Adding setInsecure(); worked for me.